# Improving conversion from List to List<Dictionary<string,string>> with Linq

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I've a Key/Value table in my DB and I would return a List of Dictionary.
The following code works fine for me but with a lot of data is not performing.

note: r.name doesn't contains unique value

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> listOutput = null;

using (ExampleDB db = new ExampleDB())
{
    var result = (from r in db.FormField
               where r.Form_id == 1
               select new { r.ResponseId, r.name, r.value}).toList();

    listOutput = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

    foreach (var element in result)
    {
        listOutput.Add((from x in listOutput
               where x.ResponseId == element.ResponseId
               select x).ToDictionary(x => x.name, x => x.value));
    }
}

return listOutput;
```

Do you have suggestions on how to improve this code ?

Comment: You're adding to the list based on the existing list, which seems pretty odd to me. I don't understand what you're trying to do - could you give a sample of input data and expected result?

Comment: I'm not sure I can understand why you are choosing a list of dictionary.  Why not just create a custom class to hold your variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *suspect* you want something like:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> result;

using (var db = new ExampleDB())
{
    result = db.FormField
               .Where(r => r.Form_id == 1)
               .GroupBy(r => r.ResponseId, r => new { r.name, r.value })
               .AsEnumerable()
               .Select(g => g.ToDictionary(p => p.name, p => p.value))
               .ToList();
}
```

In other words, we're filtering so that `r.Form_id == 1`, then grouping by `ResponseId`... taking all the name/value pairs associated with each ID and creating a dictionary from those name/value pairs.

Note that you're losing the `ResponseId` in the list of dictionaries - you can't tell which dictionary corresponds to which response ID.

The `AsEnumerable` part is to make sure that the last `Select` is performed using LINQ to Objects, rather than trying to convert it into SQL. It's *possible* that it would work without the `AsEnumerable`, but it will depend on your provider at the very least.

Comment: Exactly ! And you're right about ResponseId ... is there a way to include it in the Dictionary?

About the performance goes really well ... the response time is less than one second

Comment: @EmanueleTramutola: Well not if you want a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` because there's nowhere to put it. You might want to create a separate type for this, e.g. `Response`, which *contains* a response ID and a dictionary... then your return type would be `List<Response>`.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather you're trying to create a list of Key/Value pairs based on each `ResponseId`. Try `GroupBy`:

```
var output = result.GroupBy(r => r.ResponseId)
                   .Select(r => r.ToDictionary(s => s.Name, s => s.Value));
```

This will return an `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,string>>`, which you can `ToList` if you actually need a list.

Comment: While that should "logically" work, my suspicion is that most LINQ providers won't support that `Select` call. I could be wrong though :)